# The used as value error in go's function closure

Tags: go

I want to convert my own Handler to another, but the code under below report a error show the closure can not be executed as a value in my project.

```
// A type that handles an http request
type Handler func(ctx context.Context, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error

// A type that handles an http fileSystem
type FSHandler func(ctx context.Context, root http.FileSystem)

// Convert FSHandler to Hanlder
func FromFSHandler(handler FSHandler) Handler {
    return func(ctx context.Context, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error {
        return handler(ctx, http.Dir("/path/to/root"))
        //            ^ report `handler(cox, http.Dir("/path/to/root")) used as value` error
    }
}
```

**PS**

Thanks mkopriva for the code template.

Comment: That's because your `FSHandler` type has no return value, so to make this compile you need to move the call expression above the return statement, and just return `nil` since there is no error to be returned.

Comment: Either do this: https://play.golang.com/p/w3xd27JjVFr or this: https://play.golang.com/p/_F03UnvqvjP